# how can I align right placeholder and align left for email input in joomla comment php file?

Tags: php, forms, joomla, placeholder

I want to align email input form to left and its placeholder to right (for RTL) in a joomla php file? it has a both css file one is style.css for LTR and style_rtl.css for RTL

that code I work it is below. how to edit it for "placeholder right and email in left side"

```
<input id="comments-form-email" type="text" name="email" value="" size="22" tabindex="2" placeholder="<?php echo $text; ?>"/>
```

I have this problem on my site in end of this link (comment section):
[article comment that I have this problem](http://4power.ir/knowledge/electric-and-electronics/3-spark-quenching-in-inductive-device)

the **box 2** is input email form.

Comment: You need to JText() the $text. Joomla is designed to support RTL pretty smoothly.

Comment: my original problem is not $text because I know that. I want to "show placeholder text in right and input email form in left".

Comment: I'm still not understanding .. placeholder is an attribute of the field. By definition it  goes inside the field. If you want text to the side of a field you need to do that with the label and description. WHere you put the fields on the page is from your page layout. Do you have divs around your fields?

Comment: I use a RTL language for my website that means, I want to show "placeholder text" which is "ایمیل خود را وارد کنید" in right side of email input field. but when we want insert email address because "email address" is LTR, now I want to show blink courser go to left side for insert email? please see the end of blow link "comment section" on field 2 for email input.         http://4power.ir/knowledge/electric-and-electronics/3-spark-quenching-in-inductive-device

Comment: Are you using the field type email?

Comment: yes. I use email field in my site and I want to show "placeholder in right and email address in left position". we have CSS, PHP file.

Comment: So in your field definition you say type="email"? And when you do that it is still entering on the right?

Comment: Dear Elin. yes. If it possible, please see field 2 of my site (insert new comment section) I want to show "placeholder in right and when typing email address it be on left" ) ------> http://4power.ir/knowledge/electric-and-electronics/3-spark-quenching-in-inductive-device

Comment: I have to say this is not something I have tested but it sounds like a bug. BUt for you what I would do is make a custom field type that generates the html that you want. But I'd also maybe post a question about this on one of the joomla developer mailing lists.